# Recode values NA to correspond values of other variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How can I recode the values NA of variable `b`, with the values of the row in variable `a`.
See `df` with `a` and `b`: the expected output is `df2`.

```
a<- c(10, 12, 8, 7, 6)
b<-  c(5, NA, 6, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame (a,b)
df


 df
#    a  b
# 1 10  5
# 2 12 NA
# 3  8  6
# 4  7 NA
# 5  6 NA

# df2
#    a  b
# 1 10  5
# 2 12 12
# 3  8  6
# 4  7  7
# 5  6  6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the NA values of column B (`df$b[is.na(df$b)]`) to the values of a when b is NA (`df$a[is.na(df$b)]`)

```r
df$b[is.na(df$b)] <- df$a[is.na(df$b)]

#    a  b
# 1 10  5
# 2 12 12
# 3  8  6
# 4  7  7
# 5  6  6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple subsetting:

```
df$b <- ifelse(is.na(df$b), df$a, df$b)
```